# Why can't I use \pi or \equiv in a list?

Tags: math-mode, itemize

The problem comes when I try to use a '\' inside an item tag. In my code:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item   \pi\textsubscript{k} 
   \item   f\textsubscript{k}(x) \equiv ....
\end{itemize}
```

both `\pi` and and `\equiv` gives me an error.

How can I fix it? I'm new to LaTeX.

Comment: You need the mathematical mode: $\pi$, i.e. use the `$...$` as pair around your 'mathematical' command `\pi`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default the `itemize` environment will not be in math mode which you need to use `\pi` or `\equiv`. Try this:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item   $\pi_{k}$
   \item   $f_k(x) \equiv  ....$
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Thorsten: Now why on Earth would anyone think that a fuzzy grayed-out {} means "code"?

Comment: @jamesqf Hover the mouse over the symbol and read the tooltip ...

Comment: @jamesqf Quite a few programming languages (including TeX!) use braces as delimiters.

Comment: @Lambda Fairy:  I'm well aware of that, having used several such languages for some decades.  But why should seeing a pair of braces (which in my browser are so greyed-out as to scarce be distinguishable as such) cause me to think that they have anything to do with inserting code in a post?  Whereas the standard-almost-everywhere-else [code][/code] pair is pretty obvious.  (Honestly, if I could comprehend icons, I'd probably be using Word or Open Office instead of LaTeX.)